# What software was used for the effects in Interstellar?

Tags: interstellar

In the movie 'Interstellar' they have used pretty good real time animations with large details. I guess they may have used global illumination rendering.

There are basic software packages to make animations like Cinema4D (used in 2012), Autodesk 3ds Max, Maya and others. And renderers like V-ray or Maxwell (probably, I'm not sure used in Gravity) So my question is: which are the software packages that used in Interstellar for modelling, animating and rendering purposes?

Comment: Or possibly it’s unclear what you’re asking. Which special effects are you talking about? There’s [an interesting article on Insterstellar’s black hole effects in Wired](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/astrophysics-interstellar-black-hole/). As a physicist, you’ve probably read it, and it doesn’t specifically discuss the software (although it kind of suggests they wrote their own?).

Comment: @Paul D. Waite

There are basic softwares to make animations like, Cinema4D (used in 2012), Autodesk 3ds Max, Maya etc. And renderer like, V-ray, Maxwell (probably, I'm not sure used in Gravity) So my question is that which are the softwares that used in Interstellar. Should I edit the question with that informations? And I didn't read that article yet.

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/film-news/11274246/Interstellar-behind-the-VFX.html

Comment: @VikramadityaMondal: right, but I wasn’t asking about softwares. I was asking which special effects in the movie you’re talking about. The black hole? The spaceships? The floating ice thingies on Matt Damon’s planet? It may well be clear to someone familiar with special effects and animation software what you’re taking about already.

Comment: A potential difficulty with this question (and ones like it) is that these days, the effects for movies are not usually done by a single fx house. They're farmed out to multiple, and the final work is compiled at the end. Each contracted company can use whatever they like, so there may not be a true single answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're asking about the black hole and wormhole scenes, Kip Thorne and the others who worked on the renderings published a pair of papers on how they did it:

[Gravitational Lensing by Spinning Black Holes in Astrophysics, and in the Movie Interstellar](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03808v1)

[Visualizing Interstellar's Wormhole](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03809v1)

As mentioned in the first paper, they designed their own software called DNGR (Double Negative Gravitational Renderer):

> For this, our team at Double Negative Visual Effects, in collaboration
>   with physicist Kip Thorne, developed a code called DNGR (Double
>   Negative Gravitational Renderer) to solve the equations for ray-bundle
>   (light-beam) propagation through the curved spacetime of a spinning
>   (Kerr) black hole, and to render IMAX-quality, rapidly changing
>   images. Our ray-bundle techniques were crucial for achieving
>   IMAX-quality smoothness without flickering; and they differ from
>   physicists’ image-generation techniques (which generally rely on
>   individual light rays rather than ray bundles), and also differ from
>   techniques previously used in the film industry’s CGI community.

And on p. 3-4 they write:

> A primary goal of today’s state-of-the-art, astrophysical ray-tracing
>   codes (e.g., the Chan, Psaltis and O ̈zel’s massively parallel,
>   GPU-based code GRay [28]) is very fast throughput, measured, e.g., in
>   integration steps per second; the spatial smoothness of images has
>   been only a secondary concern. For our Interstellar work, by contrast,
>   a primary goal is smoothness of the images, so flickering is minimised
>   when objects move rapidly across an IMAX screen; fast throughput has
>   been only a secondary concern. With these different primary goals, in
>   our own code, called DNGR, we have been driven to employ a different
>   set of visualization techniques from those of the astrophysics
>   community—techniques based on propagation of ray bundles (light beams)
>   instead of discrete light rays, and on carefully designed spatial
>   filtering to smooth the overlaps of neighbouring beams; see Section 2
>   and Appendix A.

So, you can read the rest of the paper, especially Section 2 and Appendix A, for a lot more detail on how the software worked.

If you're asking about CG in other parts of the movie, Christopher Nolan tried to use physical models rather than CG as much as possible, he even claims "we made the decision early on not to do any green screens on the film" in [this video](http://screenrant.com/interstellar-movie-interview-nolan-mcconaughey-hathaway-chastain/). The ships were mostly done with physical models as discussed [here](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/real-and-raw-the-miniature-fx-behind-interstellar/) (though 'digital models' are also mentioned, for example in the depressurization scene with debris), and [this article](http://www.businessinsider.com/interstellar-making-tars-2014-12) says the robots were physical models in most scenes, only CG when shown running. Phantom42's answer has some info on what packages they used when they did have to use CG in scenes other than the black hole and wormhole.

Comment: "a code" :(​​​​

Answer (score 17):

Double Negative was the primary effects house used for *Interstellar*.

As Richard notes, [Double Negative's currently available job listings](http://www.dneg.com/jobs/) seems to indicate a fair usage of Maya as their main software package. This, alone, does not necessarily mean that they used Maya during production of *Interstellar*.

However, [this writeup about the films nominated for the best visual effects Oscar this past year](http://venturebeat.com/2015/01/15/hollywood-fx-pros-i-want-to-be-an-oscars-maya-winner/) states that all of the nominees had something in common: **They were all done with Autodesk Maya.**

> Indeed, the visual effects and animation teams on all 10 films considered for this year’s Oscar nomination, and all five that received nominations this morning, used Maya, a powerful, customizable tool that enables deeply complex processes like character animation to look seamless and realistic on the silver screen.

Maya would have likely been used for the bulk of the modeling, rigging and animation. As [this Wired article](http://www.wired.com/2014/10/astrophysics-interstellar-black-hole/) mentions, a new proprietary renderer was created for the film. Based on the job listings, Nuke was likely used for compositing the effects and live footage.

Comment: The writeup says all the movies "used Maya", but that doesn't mean all the CG effects sequences in Interstellar used Maya, just some. If Vikramaditya Mondal intended to ask about the sequences involving the black hole and wormhole which show the realistic effects of curved spacetime, I think the papers I posted suggested these were done entirely with the DNGR software they designed.

Comment: Based on everything in the articles I've read, DNGR is a *RENDERER*, not a full animation package.

Comment: What do you mean by "animation" in this context? That normally refers to animating some 3D models of objects, but there were no *objects* to animate in these scenes AFAIK, both a wormhole and a black hole are empty curved spacetimes, and all we saw was the effect these curved spacetimes had on the light from the background stars/nebulae (which were just 2D images) and the accretion disk (which section 4.1 of the first paper I posted, along with appendix A.6, seems to indicate was generated within DNGR).

Comment: Visual Effects goes far beyond just astronomical phenomena. Things like dust blowing, the tesseract, parts of ships/robots (yes, even when a physical model/prop is used), and small details are often done in animation software.

Answer (score 6):

[This article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/film-news/11274246/Interstellar-behind-the-VFX.html) states that the software used to render that the wormhole and black hole were designed in house by the lead VFX company;

> *"And then we – the team at Double Negative – turned that into a new piece of software. We wrote a thing called the Double Negative General Relativity Renderer. A renderer is a piece of software which takes all the mathematics from the computer and turns them into pictures on a screen."*

And a 30 second look at their recruitment page would suggest that their primary focus is on Maya.

Comment: A renderer is only part of the process, and does not fully answer the question.

Comment: @phantom42 - Partial answers need love too.

Comment: @phantom42 - Can you clarify what you mean by "only part of the process?" What would be the other part? Are you talking about the phrase "takes all the mathematics from the computer"? I think the article's author was speaking loosely, as far as I can tell from the papers their DNGR software did both the mathematical calculations of light bundle paths in curved spacetime, and the next step of turning that into an image made of pixels.

Comment: @Hypnosifl A renderer is one of the final pieces of the puzzle that is a 3d animation pipeline. This is the part that will calculate and generate the final particles, lights, effects, water, and compile them into the effects we actually see. Before it ever gets to the renderer, modelers, animators, riggers, lighting artists, effects artists, and others have to do work to create/program all of those things. All of *that* work is done separate of the renderer.

Comment: @Hypnosifl OP mentions various 3d software packages like maya, max, and c4d in the comments, and asking if one of them was used. Those are some of the popular apps used for 3d animation. The custom renderer would be used towards the end of the workflow with any of those apps.

Comment: @phantom42 - I have my doubts that they would use any standard 3D modeler for the black hole/wormhole scenes, because those are all designed for modeling objects in ordinary Euclidean space, they had to model things in the curved non-Euclidean spacetime of general relativity. And as far as I know the only "object" they needed to model in these scenes separate from the curved spacetime  itself was the accretion disk, but section 4.1 of the 1st paper I posted seems to indicate this was created within DNGR as well.

Comment: (continued) On the other hand, if you're talking about the use of CG in scenes that didn't involve the black hole or wormhole, the article you posted is evidence that they did use Maya somewhere in the movie, but I don't think that's what Vikramaditya Mondal intended to ask about, though it isn't entirely clear from the question.

Comment: @Hypnosifl You seem to only be considering the modeling of the astronomical objects/phenomena, something the question does *not* assume. Things like the Ranger or the space station, TARS/KIP, all need to be modeled as well. In cases like this, a basic model/object would have likely been created as the black hole in a standard modeling package and placed in the scene . Particle generators, shaders, etc would be applied to them. Then the custom renderer is used to generate the final output (which then needs to be composited).

Comment: @Hypnosifl OP in the comments: "There are basic softwares to make animations like, Cinema4D (used in 2012), Autodesk 3ds Max, Maya etc. And renderer like, V-ray, Maxwell (probably, I'm not sure used in Gravity) So my question is that which are the softwares that used in Interstellar"

Comment: @phantom42 - The Ranger and Endurance were physical models as discussed [here](http://www.fxguide.com/featured/real-and-raw-the-miniature-fx-behind-interstellar/), and the robots were models in most scenes too, according to [this article](http://www.businessinsider.com/interstellar-making-tars-2014-12) only the scenes of the robots running were CG. And I interpreted the OP's "they have used pretty good real time animations with large details" to be about the details in the black hole/wormhole scenes, though I could be wrong.

Comment: **RENDERERS are not used to create models, place lights, place effects, or shaders, or do main animations.** I don't know how much clearer I can be.

Comment: Perhaps DNGR does not fit the standard definition of a "renderer" then--when dealing with a software package designed to do something entirely unlike standard 3D packages (model the effects of curved spacetime on light bundles), I don't think you can assume the terminology will be exactly identical. Do you have any direct evidence that any other software was used in creating the black hole/wormhole sequences other than DNGR? They say in the abstract that DNGR was used to "render IMAX-quality, rapidly changing images", which certainly sounds like the final animation.

Comment: (cont) Also, I don't see how they could "place lights" using some separate software package, since existing packages are designed to place light sources in a Euclidean 3D space, not a curved non-Euclidean space. And "The Science of Interstellar" indicates the accretion disk was modeled with the same custom code: "Eugenie von Tunzelmann was charged with putting an accretion disk into Oliver James' gravitational lensing computer code".

Comment: As much as I understand, renderer is also important to get details. The same modelling redered in different renderers may give radically different details.And  I have asked for the softs used in both modelling and rendering.